# Git hook pre-push prompt to squash commits first

Tags: git, github, version-control, githooks, gitkraken

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the correct way.  Sorta new to Git and GitKraken.  I want to force others to squash their feature branch commits before pushing and creating a pull request.  So I've tried the following [pre-push git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) but even when I squash first it still thinks there are multiple commits.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

```
#!/bin/sh

# An example hook script to verify what is about to be pushed.  Called by "git
# push" after it has checked the remote status, but before anything has been
# pushed.  If this script exits with a non-zero status nothing will be pushed.
#
# This hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- Name of the remote to which the push is being done
# $2 -- URL to which the push is being done
#
# If pushing without using a named remote those arguments will be equal.
#
# Information about the commits which are being pushed is supplied as lines to
# the standard input in the form:
#
#   <local ref> <local sha1> <remote ref> <remote sha1>

remote="$1"
url="$2"

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    if [ "$local_sha" = $z40 ]
    then
        # Handle delete
        :
    else
        # Check for number of commits
        commits=`git rev-list --count "$local_sha"`
        if [ "$commits" -ne "1" ]
        then
            echo "Multiple commits detected, push aborted. Please squash your local branch before pushing."
            exit 1
            #git reset --soft HEAD~"$commits"
            #git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"
        fi
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

You want `git rev-list --count $local_sha ^$remote_sha` (but see caveat below).

#### Long

`git rev-list` is the big brother (sister?) plumbing variant of `git log`: both will, by default, *start from* the commit(s) you give them, and find *every commit reachable from those commits*.

That is, given a commit graph like:

```
... <-E <-F <-G   <-- branchname
```

you tell Git to start from `branchname`, which identifies commit `G` (`G` here stands in for the actual 40-character hash ID), so `git log` shows you that commit.  Then, since `G` has `F` as its parent (`G` points to `F`), `git log` shows you `F`.  Since `F` has `E` as its parent, `git log` shows you `E` next, and so on.

The rev-list code does the same thing: you tell it where to start—`$local_sha`—and it lists that commit's hash, and its parent(s) hash(es), and more hashes of their parents, and so on.  Adding `--count` makes it count them up, and there are probably many.

You need to tell the Git commands that walk the graph *where to stop*.  Given:

```
E--F--G   <-- branchname
```

you can tell `git rev-list` to start at `G` (by hash ID, or by name), but to *stop* (and not include) `E` (by hash ID, or by name if there's a name that points to `E`).  You can name stopping-point commits in many ways, but the most direct is the hat-prefix: `^E` means *stop at `E`, or any commit reachable from `E`*.

This *reachability* notion is very important in more complex graphs:

```
  B--C
 /    \
A      F--G   <-- branchname
 \    /
  D--E
```

The arrows connecting commits (which I've been drawing as lines here) are all one-way: they all point backwards in time.  So `F` points back to both `E` and `C` here, because `F` here is a *merge commit*.  `C` points back to `B`, which points back to `A`; `E` points back to `D`, which also points back to `A`.

If you name `E` as a stopping point and `G` as the starting point, `git rev-list` will skip commits `E`, `D`, and `A`, but will still include commits `B` and `C`, because those are reachable from `F`.  To exclude `B` and `C` as well, you must add `^C` to your list of stopping points.

In general, in a pre-push hook, you can just list the remote hash as the (single) stopping point, but there's a more general problem: you might not *have* the commit that the remote-hash points-to.  You get commits from the remote by running `git fetch`.  They—the other repository to which you are `git push`ing—get commits by someone committing there, or by other people also `git push`ing to that repository.  You might not have their commit(s) yet.  If so, you'll have to run `git fetch` first, so that your own Git has the commit, so that your Git can walk the commit graph starting from their hash ID.